# Driving in Canada with a US probationary license

Tags: usa, canada, driving-licenses

I am holding a US probationary driving license in US (Issued in New Jersey) and I planned to visit Canada (British Columbia) soon.

I know that if you hold a full driving license, then it can be used in Canada. But I did not find anything about the probationary license though.

A probationary license is what we get when we pass the written and road test. We can drive on our own (with restrictions).

A similar questions [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16968/can-i-use-my-probationary-australian-drivers-license-to-rent-a-car-in-the-unite) with different countries.

**Remark**: Since the question attracts some attention, let me record my experience: A week after I asked this question, I flew to BC (with a passport of course) and, once cleared custom, went to a car rental at the airport (Avis or Hertz, can't remember). I showed them my probationary license, then they gave me the key. Of course this is just a single encounter. It would be great if someone could provide the official policy, which I cannot find online.

Comment: Do you have a passport too?

Comment: Whose car will you be driving?

Comment: @CrossRoads a US citizen can't generally fly to Canada without a passport.  If Artic Char is planning to drive from NJ to BC, it will also be necessary to check what restrictions will apply to the probationary license in several US states as well as in BC.  But even then it's likely that a passport will be necessary, since the other [WHTI-compliant documents](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative/faqs) seem unlikely to apply in this case (NJ does not issue enhanced licenses).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are driving to British Columbia and from the description, the NJ probationary licence is the equivalent of the BC N(new driver) licence, with almost identical restrictions. Since N drivers are explicitly allowed to drive in the US:
http://drivinginstructorblog.com/l-and-n-restrictions/, you'll be fine.